# Track source of heavy NFS usage?

Tags: networking, nfs

The NFS my group uses has been getting extremely sluggish recently.

Is it possible to track the processes, across a network of multiple machines of course, that are causing this heavy usage?

Perhaps, say, something that shows which machine on the network is causing a lot of NFS traffic, and then I could find what processes on that machine could be using that traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what version of Unix you are using. If your version of unix supports [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace), you can try [this DTrace Script](https://blogs.oracle.com/erickustarz/entry/dscript_to_retrieve_active_nfs).

Another option is to simple monitor traffic with [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor the NFS traffic to narrow down the machine.